# What does it mean to say "Someone won't know I'm there"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, differences, american-english

In one of the video clips of SNL(https://is.gd/WVr1OQ), the man said the thing that drives his mom crazy is "when he sometimes wake up earlier than his mom, he gets out of their bed so that his mom won't know he's there." Does the sentence mean the same as his mom will know he's not there?

Comment: I listened to it. That's hard to read or this would be an answer. From his playfulness it could well mean he is fooling her by, as you say, letting her think he *is* there. Normally *not knowing you're there* is a promise to be unnoticeable, so as not to be a burden or observer in a situation. The double negative/entendre is getting a bit thick in this piece.

Comment: *Not knowing he is there* is different to *knowing he is not there*: the former is an absence of knowledge, the latter is knowledge of absence.